# "No persistence unit with name" error when running "mvn clean compile jib:build" command

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple SpringBoot application and I want to build docker image using Jib Maven plugin. Following is my plugin configuration:

```
    <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.7.0</version>
     <configuration>
    <source>17</source>
    <target>17</target>
    </configuration>
              </plugin>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <from>
                    <image>eclipse-temurin:17.0.4.1_1-jre</image>
                </from>
                <to>
                    <image>registry.hub.docker.com/mauricio503/${project.artifactId}</image>
                </to>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>dockerBuild</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

when running "mvn clean compile jib:build" it seems that it is not recognizing persistence.xml in my project, and if you just run "maven install" function

Comment: Is the `persistence.xml` file present on the classpath, i.e. `src/main/resources`?

Comment: Removed jib tag since its not clear what is returning your error. Edit with the actual maven output

Comment: Solved it by adding the persistence.xml in the src/main/resource folder